# How to get submitted form data from passed token

Tags: token, drupal-8, submission, drupal-webform

In Drupal 8 (latest version) I have multi step webform created with webform module. After last step submitted I end up on confirmation page, which url looks like:

```
/node/1/webform/confirmation?token=KxCIo9eUxHC_XJKtDG8erszn5BL5UHBZnRrvJU7Kirw
```

Now, I want to create custom confirmation page and I already created module which creates custom page and that works. It suppose to be called the similar way:

```
/confirmation?token=KxCIo9eUxHC_XJKtDG8erszn5BL5UHBZnRrvJU7Kirw
```

My question is: how can I use this token value to collect submitted form data?

Tried something like this from my confirmation page controller:

```
        $token = \Drupal::request()->query->get('token');

        $webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($token);

        // Get submission data.
        $data = $webform_submission->getData();

//        var_dump($data);
```

`$token` value is collected well, but when I try to use it to get that `$webform_submissions` I get null value and collecting `$data` of course fails at the next row.

That `load()` method is expecting `$sid` (session id) and I'm not sure is this token that id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution by looking at webform module confirmation action. Goes like this:

```
    $token = \Drupal::request()->query->get('token');


    if ($token) {
        /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionStorageInterface $webform_submission_storage */
        $webform_submission_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');
        if ($entities = $webform_submission_storage->loadByProperties(['token' => $token])) {
            $webform_submission = reset($entities);
        }
        $data = $webform_submission->getData();

        var_dump($data);
    }
```